# How To Import Date column into 2 separate fields at the same time, a varchar field and a date field?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a sales data file that is imported in MySQL [Workbench] from a CSV on a weekly basis. One of the columns contains dates in the format of 1/5/2023. I would like to import the date into 2 columns:

- One column is called "Date" (varchar type), with intended result of 1/5/2023.
- The other column is called "sql_date" (date type), with intended result of 2023-01-05.

How can I import this cleanly in one swoop WITHOUT an UPDATE/SET/WHERE additional statement at the end?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Lachelle Kazda/Desktop/Date Import Test.csv'

INTO TABLE sales_table
    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS

(@Date, sales_amt, sales_qty)
SET sql_date = STR_TO_Date(@Date,'%c/%e/%Y')
AND @Date = Date
```

RESULT: This nulls out. Can I insert the 1 date in this way somehow?

Note: For clarity, original columns are (Date, sales_amt, sales_qty, sql_date)

Comment: ```SET sql_date = STR_TO_DATE(@Date,'%c/%e/%Y'), `date` = @Date```

Comment: Your code performs `sql_date = (STR_TO_Date(@Date,'%c/%e/%Y') AND (@Date = Date))` which obviously produces non-date value and results in NULL assignment.

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you!!!